# How to prevent PDF file in secure folder from crawling and indexing from robot.txt dnn7

Tags: dotnetnuke

End user got published all documents by mistake which is located to standard folder.To correct that mistake.

```
I have moved that file to secure folder. But I was not able to resolve problem robot.txt. so How to prevent PDF file in secure folder from crawling and indexing from robot.txt dnn7
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to write the command in robots.txt to ask bots not to crawl a particular folder or location?

Comment: this should help http://www.robotstxt.org/